# Removing last anchor tag from list

Tags: jquery

Hi all I have a Ul with a class of breadcrumb on it. then some li and inside them a link. As you can guess its a dynamic breadcrumb trail. I want to remove the link of the last li.

I have the following code but as you can guess its not working

```
  $('.breadcrumb li').last('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to delete the (one) link inside the last li or do you want to remove the last link inside the last li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the (one) `a` inside the last `li` go for this version, there is no use of selecting the last `a` since there is only one `a` inside the `li`:

```
$('.breadcrumb li:last a').removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.breadcrumb li:last a').removeAttr('href');
```

or:

```
$('.breadcrumb li:last a').removeAttr('href');
```

or:

```
$('.breadcrumb li').last().find('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.breadcrumb li:nth-last-child(1)').find('a').removeAttr('href');

or

 $('.breadcrumb li:last').find('a').removeAttr('href');
```